# Visual Studio C++ Runtime Dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I followed some solutions that I was given here about how to get rid of the missing vcruntime140.dll and msvcp140.dll errors but it didn't solve my problem.
I changed the linker to /MT for release and /MTd for debug, but when I try it on different windows 10 machines it says the spoken DLLs are missing, Ive searched for a solution everywhere but all I saw was changing the linker to be static, like I did.

If someone can help me solve this issue it will be much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

P.S - I need to exe to be independent and without any installation.

Comment: Don't use static if you can avoid it, and ship[ your app with the redistributable package for C++. The C runtime (vcruntime140) should already deployed on W10. Shipping the static version is doable but has its own inconveniences.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I want my exe to be a standalone exe and has no dependencies...

Comment: Do you use any third party libraries with your code? If so these need to be statically linked as well to avoid the runtime dependency.

Comment: You will always have dependencies. But then compile everything with static runtime, and hope that you are not falling in one of the pitfalls of static runtimes.

Comment: @drescherjm These are the includes I have: #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I am compiling everything with a static runtime but still get the missing runtime dlls message..

Comment: Then you still have something you missed somewhere.

Comment: Did you do a clean build? Do you have any libraries in your project?

Comment: It is a compile option, not a linker option.  A traditional mistake is to change the setting for the Debug configuration but forgetting to also do it for the Release configuration.  Pay attention to the two combo-boxes at the top of the settings dialog.

Comment: @HansPassant I know and I have changed both the Release and the Debug, Release for /MT and debu for /MTd, still doesnt work

Comment: @drescherjm What you see is everything I use, this is a simple code

Comment: My advice to you is try a "Hello World" application.

Comment: @drescherjm The "Hello world" app works, but the rest don't :/